# What was the earliest reference to turnover maneuvers for constant-boost spaceships?

Tags: history-of, space-travel

Turnover maneuver -- it's how you avoid a period of microgravity ("zero-gee" or "weightlessness") near the middle of a constant boost brachistochrone journey in your impossible torch ship.  You know, Earth to Mars at opposition is only a week at 1 G -- but if it takes you an hour to turn the ship with those tiny attitude jets, you have to stop boosting sooner in order not to start retro-burning too late.

Various authors have called it various things -- E.E. "Doc" Smith called it a "skew-flip" in *Spacehounds of IPC* (1947, maybe earlier if it was serialized first).  Heinlein just called it "turnover" in *Have Space Suit, Will Travel* (but good grief, five days at 8 G to Pluto?!), likewise in *Time for the Stars*, and noted in the former that if you did 8G headed for Alpha Centauri, you'd "almost touch lightspeed" at turnover.

Regardless what you call it, with careful course plotting, it's possible to make your turnover without shutting down the drive -- you'll kick a little to one side while the drive is aimed off your course, but you'd compensate for that before and after.  Do it well enough, and passengers won't even notice, even though "We used to spin 'em dizzy back then" as one of the bridge crew said to another in the first pages of *Spacehounds*.

So, Heinlein wrote turnovers in the 1950s, Smith had 'em no later than 1947.  Did Campbell use turnover in the Arcot, Morey, and Wade stories (*The Black Star Passes* and such), or did someone else have it first -- or was the idea originated by Smith?

Who had it first?

Comment: Heinlein mentioned the skew flip in *Have Spacesuit, Will Travel.*

Comment: @ancientswordrage I'm not sure the `hard-sci-fi` tag is right here.  Torch ships and Smith's ships' ability to exceed lightspeed were pretty soft even when written,  At a minimum, they depended on physics that contradicted what was then accepted (in order to make a better story).  Smith, especially, was more space opera than hard SF.

Comment: @ZeissIkon possibly? The Maneuver itself seems grounded in real world science just applied in a fictional way/story. It also felt off having [tag:history-of] there and no other tag. Ideas?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I tried to put `space-travel` on it, but we don't seem to have that tag, and similar ones all have definitions that preclude this use.  Suggestions?

Comment: I've added that tag

Comment: Seems good.  I'll wait a day or two, but I doubt we'll find anything older than the 1928 *Skylark* starter...

Comment: I think the hard-science tag is justified. The torch ships in Heinlein's *Time for the Stars* obey relativity (but the story does use telepathy for FLT comms, and that doesn't sit well with time dilation). The ships in Doc Smith's *Skylark* exceed lightspeed, but they still basically follow Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @PM2Ring `hard-science` is a Worldbuilding tag, and would surely not be suitable here if this were there (if you follow me) because this isn't asking for equations and citations.  Actually, there were problems with the telepathy as the dilation became significant -- they lost contact entirely close to turnover, IIRC (which was only a day or two aboard ship, but years back on Earth).  Yep, Smith pretty completely ignored relativity, despite it being published in 1916 -- though in fairness, if he'd included it, it would have screwed up his story; he'd have been the first major author to use it.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'd argue it's still relevant as softer sci-fi would ignore the necessity of such a maneuver, right?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage If I ask about the science behind the fiction, my question will be closed as off topic.  I'm only asking when this minor trope first appeared, and it appears it was a couple decades earlier than I had thought.  *Skylark* was much more space opera than hard SF, even for the 1920s-1930s time frame.  Might have masqueraded as such, like *The Expanse* does (and let's just ignore their torch drives), but unlike a lot of, say, Hal Clement's work, it wasn't constrained by the best science of the day, with only FTL added so there's actually a story.

Comment: Hard science fiction is an actual genre though, so you might get people navigating to this question from that tag.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Hard SF, yes, but not "hard science" as suggested above.  I've added that tag,

Comment: @ZeissIkon Ok, I should've said Hard SF. Smith agreed that the science in *Skylark* was pseudo, but at least it was consistent, so you can ask questions about its in-universe science and get meaningful answers, not just techno-babble. A major element of the marketing of E. E. 'Doc' Smith's stories was that they were written by a guy with a PhD. He was *actually* a food scientist, an expert in donuts and pastries, not a rocket scientist, but hey. ;)

Comment: The 1st Skylark story briefly mentions Einstein's theories, since it involves liberating atomic energy. The problem of *c* being a speed limit is brushed aside, with the empirical discovery by Seaton showing that Einstein got that bit wrong.

Comment: Yep, I attended Doc Smith's *alma mater*, University of Idaho.  He was still something of a celebrity there (and not for his academic achievements) as late as 1980.  And I do now recall something about "those rules don't apply to self-propelled objects" or similar -- so you can't push an electron to light speed in an accelerator, but a ship with copper drive bars plated with Element X would get there (though he might have failed to mention it takes a *year* at 1 G).

Comment: Smith's impact on the genre was enormous. SF without Smith is comparable to rock music without the Beatles. It's really difficult to write diamond-hard SF, unless you're Greg Egan. ;) And that style doesn't appeal to everyone. Most readers won't mind if a little bit of strict scientific accuracy is sacrificed for the sake of good plot development.

Comment: Yes, Heinlein does mention some problems with the telepathic link when the dilation is extreme, and when there's a kink due to the skew-flip. But he ignores that the dilation should (mostly) be reciprocal: each twin should perceive the other's clock as running slow.

Comment: Feel free to continue conversing in [chat]; I'll be clearing these comments soon otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure it was the first, but [The Skylark of Space](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/20869) by E.E. "Doc" Smith and Lee Hawkins Garby, published (in serial in Amazing Stories) in 1928 mentions having to flip the space-ship over to slow down. From page 535(? probably the page# of the magazine; chapter IX "Lost in Space"), the "bar" in mention is the unit that applies the acceleration and is pointed in the direction that they want to move/accelerate. Emphasis is mine:

> He placed one of the extra power bars in the chamber and pushed the speed lever into the first notch, and there was a lurch of the whole vessel as it swung around the **bar so that the floor was once more perpendicular to it.** He took a couple of steps, returned, and advanced the lever another notch.
> "There that's about the same as gravity. Now we can act like human beings and eat in comfort."
> "That's a wonderful relief, Doctor!" cried Dorothy. "Are we going back toward the earth?"
> "Not yet. **I reversed the bar, but we will have to use up all of this one before we can even start back. Until this bar is gone we will merely be slowing down."**

And chapter X, "The Rescue":

> They calculated their own speed, and that of the other vessel, as shown by the various readings taken, and applied just enough negative acceleration to slow the Skylark down to the speed of the other space-car when they should come up with it. They smiled at each other in recognition of the perfect working of the mechanism when the **huge vessel had spun, with a sickening lurch, through a complete half-circle, the instant the power was reversed. Each knew that they were actually traveling in a direction that to them seemed "down," but with a constantly diminishing velocity, even though they seemed to be still going "up" with an increasing speed.**

Comment: Okay, I only read the *Skylark* series once, forty-some years ago.  Must have forgotten this bit.  That's a gimbaled drive chamber, BTW, so the ship is literally spinning around the power bar -- not quite a skew-flip, but unquestionably a turnover maneuver.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I was reading it literally last week; that's the only reason I knew about the flip.